# Numpy select different number of first elements from each numpy array row

Tags: performance, numpy, vectorization

I want to select different number of first elements from matrix.
Numbers are specified in an array.
And result is one dimensional array.
For example:

```
a = np.arange(25).reshape([5, 5])
numbers = np.array([3, 2, 0, 1, 2])
```

And I want this result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 15, 20, 21]
```

without for loop.

Answer (score 5):

Let's use some [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) magic!

```
a[numbers[:,None] > np.arange(a.shape[1])]
```

Sample run -

```
In [161]: a
Out[161]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

In [162]: numbers
Out[162]: array([3, 2, 0, 1, 2])

In [163]: numbers[:,None] > np.arange(a.shape[1]) # Mask to select elems
Out[163]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [164]: a[numbers[:,None] > np.arange(a.shape[1])] # Select w/ boolean indexing
Out[164]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  5,  6, 15, 20, 21])
```

Comment: I have a huge matrix and I need to select only a tiny fraction of first elements. So this approach will build a huge mask matrix to get a very very tiny amount of data. So asymptotic will be O(N*N) instead of O(N).  And maybe a "for" loop will be faster. Is there a different approach to solve this problem?

Comment: @Stepochkin Are you running out of memory with this approach? If not, this would still be very efficient. What's the datasize that is shape of input array? Being a boolean array, the memory requirement would be `O(N*N)/8`.

Comment: I call this 100 times with matrix shape (10000, 2000)

Comment: @Stepochkin Are you running out of memory with this approach?

Comment: No I have enough memory. I tried Cython implementation and got 50 times faster function.

Comment: @Stepochkin Awesome! Guess cython is the way to go for such problems.